# Improve solution for to find odd occurrences in List using scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to solve the question
https://medium.com/@sichangpark/codility-2-1-arrays-oddoccurrencesinarray-cf4c1f7d7caf

```
  def oddCoccurance2(list: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (list.size == 1)
      print(list)
    val listUpdated = list.sorted
    for (i <- 0 until listUpdated.size by 2) {
      if (i + 1 == listUpdated.size)
        return listUpdated(i)
      else if (listUpdated(i) != listUpdated(i + 1))
        return listUpdated(i)
    }
    -1
  } 
 val res = oddCoccurance2(List(9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9))
 print(res)
```

Can I get rid of multiple return statement and any better way to improve

Comment: It would be better to add a text explanation of the problem rather than a link to a blog post. - Also, do you have some restrictions about how to solve this problem? because it can be easily solved using `groupMapReduce`; or using a simple _tail-recursive_ algorithm.

Comment: `list.reduce(_ ^ _)`. That kind of super-contrived problems often just check if you know how to abuse the bitwise xor :)

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov good one! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing an "imperative" loop is (almost) never the "right" solution in scala. Having to write a `return` is usually another indication that something is wrong.

Also, sorting the list in the beginning is inefficient.
Something like this would solve this in linear time:

```
list.groupBy(identity).collectFirst { case (_, n::Nil) => n }
```

But, as pointed out in the comments, this particular problem can even be solved with constant space as well: with just  `list.reduce(_^_)`

Comment: Can you explain the solution plz

Comment: `groupBy` creates a map with keys being original elements, and values being lists of occurrences of the same element. `collectFirst` finds and returns the first element that only occurred ones. Feel free to run each step in a REPL, and see what it does.

Comment: list.groupBy(identity) returned Map(7 -> List(7), 9 -> List(9, 9, 9, 9), 3 -> List(3, 3)), but I am unable to undestand the case match case(_,n::Nil) => n
_ represents key in map , n::Nil is not clear? how does it makes sure we group by will keep element with occurance as the first element

Comment: When using `collectFirst`, map is treated as an iterable of (key, value) tuples. The pattern `case (_, n :: Nil) =>` says match 2-tuple, first element can be anything, second element must be a list of shape `n :: Nil`, which is a list with 1 element. We assign that element to `n` and return it.

Answer (score -1):

This C++ code gives 100% and O(N*log(N))

```
#include <algorithm>

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
// write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)

long n = A.size();
//actually, n should be odd by definition, and needs to be checked, but we can 
//trust Codality :)

//Sort the array immediately by standard tools, you would not make it better   
sort(A.begin(), A.end());

for (int i = 0; i <(int) A.size(); i++){
    if(A[i]!=A[i+1]) return A[i];
    else i++;
   }
//in case of empty submission, just return 0
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged _scala_.